# How do I send results(rows) of sql query to view and display in table in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, npgsql

I have this method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Report()
    {
        string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "../00002165_Report.sql");

        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=6060;Database=hotelreal;"))
        {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", reader["fName"], reader["lName"], reader["preference"]));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 

            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

As you can see, it executes the sql query and writes the results in console. But what I want to do is something like this:

Save the results returned from the query in an array. Send  this array to view and display it in a table.

How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't it basic thing you should start from when learning MVC? [Views and UI Rendering in ASP.NET MVC Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @Reniuz I know the basic stuff but I have problems with sql script execution. I want something like `var data = cmd.ExecuteQuery()` and `return View(data)`. I tried `ExecuteScalar()` but it is not what I want I think

Comment: You can create for example List<Tuple<string, string, string>> and add new tuple in it in every loop iteration. Something like this: list.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(reader["fName"], reader["lName"], reader["preference"])); Or create some kind of ViewModel class and use it instead of tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just say create a model as below:

```
public class ReportDataModel
{
   public string fName{get; set;}
   public string lName{get; set;}
   public string preferences{get;set;}
}
```

Next create List of that model in your controller as below:

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
     string sql = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "../00002165_Report.sql");
     List<ReportDataModel> model=new List<ReportDataModel>();
     using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;User Id=postgres;Password=6060;Database=hotelreal;"))
     {
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, con);
            con.Open();
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            try
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    model.Add(
                       new ReportDataModel() {
                           fName = reader["fName"], 
                           lName = reader["lName"],
                           preferences= reader["preference"]
                       });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { 

            }
     }

     return View(model);
}
```

in your view create `IEnumerable` list of model and display through looping as below:

```
@model IEnumerable<ReportDataModel>

@foreach(var report in Model)
{
    //display report.fName
    //display report.lName
    //display report.preferences

}
```

Comment: Anytime!! Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Make a model class for example Report and give 3 properties which are FName, LName and Preference

```
public class Report
{
  public String FName {get; set;}
  public String LName {get; set;}
  public String Preferences {get; set;}
}
```

Collect the data from database and assign it to a list

```
List<Report> Reports=new List<Report>();
Report r;
while (reader.Read())
{
  r=new Report();
  r.FName=reader["fName"];
  r.LName=reader["lName"];
  r.Preferences=reader["preference"];
  Reports.Add(r);
}
```

And finally pass the list to the view at the very bottom of your code

```
return View(Reports);
```